# Bindings: best practice to bind between properties controllers

Tags: ember.js

Here's a common scenario

A LoginController which performs a login and contain a calculated boolean property named 'isLoggedIn',

An ApplicationController that perform binding to the LoginController 'isLoggedIn' property so views can easily access the property from anywhere.

In order for this to work, the binding must occur on a specific controller instance:

http://jsbin.com/asivap/1/

Please notice that I've created a LoginController instance:

```
App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.create({
   ...
```

While most examples only extends controllers and let the application create instances,
But if I change the code to

```
App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extends({
   ...
```

Then the binding doesn't work,

So what is the best practice to perform such bindings between controllers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ember uses an IOC container that instantiates controllers, routes, etc. You never instantiate a controller directly, Ember does this for you with its IOC container. The `extends` is correct.

The binding doesn't work because you are binding to a class property and using an instance property in the template.

To bind between controllers you use the `needs` API.

```
needs: 'login',
loginBinding: 'controllers.login'
```

This gives you a reference to the login controller with `this.get('login')`.

Here's your updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uqonol/1/edit).

Comment: Hoh, I had to think about the DI concept of needs combined with bindings, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!